# CustomXML In Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, mailmerge, presentationml

I want to create a PowerPoint template. I want the template to have references to items like NAME and the like based on an external source. I know with WordprocessingML I can just make a reference to an XML file and supply an x-path, but I also hear this is not supported in PowerPoint.

So how do I do this with PresentationML? Are repeaters possible if there are multiple objects to bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same as PowerPoint doesn't have Content Controls like Word. That said, you can bind almost any object in PowerPoint with CustomXML (see "CustomerData" in the object model) and make your own repeaters through code.

Comment: Do you have any examples of this? PowerPoint doesn't seem to support DataBinding of CustomXML and I'm hesitant to use VBA because users could have this disabled via security.

Comment: Not sure what type of scenario you're looking for (VSTO development, OpenXML, etc.), but these two links may help to get you started:
http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2009/08/13/adding-repeating-data-to-powerpoint.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/18/creating-a-presentation-report-based-on-data.aspx